async_read_some() operation not getting run even when socket has received data?

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

    int acceptingCounter = 0;

    std::array<char, 2048> message_buffer;

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    std::vector<tcp::endpoint * > active_connections;
    std::vector< tcp::socket * > mySocks;

    //Create a tcp::acceptor object to listen for new connections.
    //Initialised to listen on port 13.

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1025));
    bool reading = false;

    std::cout << "Accepting..." << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {

        if (acceptingCounter < 1){ 

            tcp::socket * sock = new tcp::socket(io_context);
            tcp::endpoint * endpoint = new tcp::endpoint;

            // mySocks.push_back(sock);
            acceptor.async_accept(*sock,*endpoint,[endpoint,&active_connections, &acceptingCounter, &mySocks, sock](boost::system::error_code e)
            {
                active_connections.push_back(endpoint);
                mySocks.push_back(sock);
                
                std::cout << "Client newly accepted on: " << *endpoint << std::endl;
            });
            acceptingCounter++;
        }

        if (active_connections.size() > 0)
        {
            if (!reading){
                for (tcp::socket * s : mySocks){
                     reading = true;
                     s->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(message_buffer), [&message_buffer,s,&reading, mySocks](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
                     {
                          //some completion code
                       reading = false;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        

        io_context.poll();
        io_context.restart();

        //delete all endpoints and delete all sockets.
     
    }
    return 0;
}


So I've got a server script here and I can't seem to figure out why the async_read_some completion code never gets run. As I get my client to successfully send data to this socket and io_context.poll() or even using run() never seems to run the completion code or the asynchronous operation is never seen as "completed" as I understand so it's never run.
Why exactly is it never seen as completed, the socket object doesn't go out of scope and even when using a blocking read() on the socket I'm unable to get past it and actually see the received data? Note that I do have the completion lambda function actually print it's not just commented out as shown here but nothing gets shown. The client definitely sends data because I get no error codes and the completion handler for async_send() is run on that side. I also checked that it is accepting and trying to read on the same socket by looking at the remote endpoint but it doesn't work.

Recommendation: finish off the code example by adding the required headers. The more changes people have to make beating your code into something they can compile, the more likely they are to insert new mistakes or accidentally fix the problem. Doesn't happen much with missing headers, but when it does...

To see what's actually happening on the wire, I recommend checking out WireShark.

See also [mre] and SSCCE.

So, there's many issues with your code. The main one seems to be that it's working.
I made it self-contained:
Live On Coliru
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    int acceptingCounter = 0;

    std::array<char, 2048> message_buffer;

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    std::vector<tcp::endpoint*> active_connections;
    std::vector<tcp::socket*>   mySocks;

    // Create a tcp::acceptor object to listen for new connections.
    // Initialised to listen on port 13.

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1025));
    bool          reading = false;

    std::cout << "Accepting..." << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Active connections: " << active_connections.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Accepting counter: " << acceptingCounter << std::endl;
        if (acceptingCounter < 1) {

            tcp::socket*   sock     = new tcp::socket(io_context);
            tcp::endpoint* endpoint = new tcp::endpoint;

            // mySocks.push_back(sock);
            acceptor.async_accept( //
                *sock, *endpoint,
                [endpoint, &active_connections /*, &acceptingCounter*/, &mySocks, sock](error_code e) {
                    std::cout << "Client newly accepted on: " << *endpoint << " (" << e.message()
                              << std::endl;
                    active_connections.push_back(endpoint);
                    mySocks.push_back(sock);
                });
            acceptingCounter++;
        }

        if (active_connections.size() > 0) {
            if (!reading) {
                for (tcp::socket* s : mySocks) {
                    reading = true;
                    s->async_read_some(
                        boost::asio::buffer(message_buffer),
                        [/*&message_buffer, s,*/ &reading, mySocks](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                            std::cout << "Received: " << transferred << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")"
                                      << std::endl;
                            // some completion code

                            reading = false;
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        io_context.run();
        io_context.restart();
        // delete all endpoints and delete all sockets.
    }
}

With the live demo on Coliru, or locally:

Problems
You have memory leaks, race conditions, unnecessary dynamic allocation, using raw new/delete but also

the accept loop never accepts a new connection
the whole concept of asio is to abstract the event loop, you're hardcoding it with a gigantic amount of state as if you're writing C-style epoll/select code. This means that you cannot even have two reads on separate connections in parallel. That's antithetical to the purpose of asynchronous IO.

Here's my suggestion to fix it:
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    tcp::socket            sock;
    tcp::endpoint          ep = sock.remote_endpoint();
    std::array<char, 2048> message_buffer;

    Session(tcp::socket sock) : sock(std::move(sock)) { std::cout << "New session: " << ep << std::endl; }
    ~Session() { std::cout << "Close session: " << ep << std::endl; }

    void start() { do_read(); }

    void do_read() {
        sock.async_read_some(asio::buffer(message_buffer),
                             [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                                 std::cout << ep << ": Received: " << transferred << " bytes ("
                                           << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                                 // some completion code

                                 do_read();
                             });
    }
};


int main() {
    asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp::acceptor    acceptor(io_context, {{}, 1025});

    std::cout << "Accepting..." << std::endl;

    std::function<void()> accept_loop;

    accept_loop = [&acceptor, &accept_loop]() {
        acceptor.async_accept([&](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            std::cout << "Accepted (" << ec.message() << "): " << (ec ? tcp::endpoint{} : s.remote_endpoint())
                      << std::endl;

            if (!ec) {
                std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s))->start();
                accept_loop();
            }
        });
    };

    accept_loop();

    io_context.run();
}

Which does support multiple concurrent connections without the problems. Note there's a single run() and everything happens indirectly from the accept_loop:


Added an ASIO-style version which simplifies many of the issues. It's more typical to have a class to group accept_loop with the acceptor. Also, if you can use C++20, do so: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/deafe9925f671bb4 It does the exact same thing but even simpler
